# Get windows taskbar items

Tags: c#, c++, windows, winapi

Any idea how to get all task bar items details in windows .I am looking for a notification if some thing new process came on task bar list

Comment: What is with processes that don´t show up in task-bar? Apart from this you have to provide some own as per [the rules of this site](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: There's no easy way to do this, so the question to you is why you need this information because you are going to need to solve your underlying problem a different way

Answer (score 3):

There is no official API to directly enumerate taskbar items, or query any details about them.

A Taskbar button is created for:

- a visible top-level unowned window, or a visible window that has the `WS_EX_APPWINDOW` extended style.  These windows can easily be discovered using an [`EnumWindows()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633497.aspx) callback that checks each available window using [`IsWindowVisible ()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633530.aspx), [`GetParent()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633510.aspx)/[`GetWindow(GW_OWNER)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633515.aspx),  [`GetWindowLongPtr(GWL_EXSTYLE)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633585.aspx), etc.
- a window that is added to the Taskbar manually using [`ITaskbarList::AddTab()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774646.aspx).  These windows cannot be enumerated.  The only way I can think to discover them is to replace the standard `CLSID_TaskbarList` COM object with a custom DLL implementation that intercepts all `ITaskbarList` calls across all processes.

Comment: One can use [UI automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff486375(v=vs.85).aspx) to enumerate taskbar buttons and possibly also listen to events when a taskbar button is added or removed.